# Windows installation once Ubuntu 18 is already installed

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have Ubuntu 18 installed on my laptop's SSD and I would like to install Windows 10 in a partition that I've made on the HDD drive.

I haven't started because I have some doubts related with the GRUB. Is it completely safe to install Windows after Ubuntu is already installed? Will I have to do something (GRUB re-installation or mount related things) even when I'm installing Windows on a different hard drive?

I need to keep all my Ubuntu files and software as it is my main OS and I will only use Windows to play some games.

I know there are several similar threads but none of them solves this particular issue, in my opinion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on my computer a few months ago. Since you are installing Windows on a different partition, then all data of your Ubuntu will be safe.

However, Windows doesn't like to live together with other operating systems. Therefore, it will **remove** the GRUB from your machine, and you will need to reinstall it. The links below present strategies to recover your GRUB.

- [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)
- [How to install grub after installing Windows 10 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685910/how-to-install-grub-after-installing-windows-10)