# Install Windows after Ubuntu in a different drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a new ssd for my laptop. It currently has Ubuntu 20.04 installed in a M.2 drive and I will like to install the new SATA SSD and install Windows 10 on it. I don´t want to reinstall Ubuntu.
Do I really need to unplug the M.2 drive to install Windows, to avoid any problem with Windows partitions? Topics in different forums indicate to do so but M.2 drive may be difficult to access.
Anyone has ever done what I´m trying to do?
I know all the problems with GRUB that can happen after installation, but there is alot of information to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows installation once Ubuntu 18 is already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080360/windows-installation-once-ubuntu-18-is-already-installed) and [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6317/)

Comment: In the links provide, a user says that it is safe in a BIOS computer but totally unsafe in UEFI machine, as I have.

Comment: Most UEFI allow you to disable a drive. So you do not have to physically remove it. Check UEFI settings and the drive settings available. Often same place as you used to change to AHCI. Both installs need to be in UEFI boot mode and how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS/Legacy is then how it installs.

Comment: Finally; everything goes OK, no issues with the Ubuntu drive, excepting the known issue of having to repair boot on Ubuntu to allow dual boot. Just boot with a live USB of Ubuntu, and install/run grub-repair-